# How this thing work ? "if all(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string)"?

Tags: python

This program is written in python and should convert from binary to decimal.

```py
# Prompt the user to enter a binary string
binary_string = input("Enter a binary string (only 1s and 0s): ")

# Check if the input string contains only 0s and 1s
if all(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string):

    # Convert the binary string to decimal and print the result
    decimal_equivalent = int(binary_string, 2)
    print("Decimal equivalent:", decimal_equivalent)

else:
    print("Invalid input! Please enter a binary string containing only 1s and 0s.")
```

**but I don't actually understand how this line work**

```py
# Check if the input string contains only 0s and 1s
if all(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string):
```

can someone help please!

---

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether for each `bit in binary_string` the condition `bit in '01'` holds. In other words, it checks whether `binary_string` consists only of zeros and ones.

Since the string `'01'` is iterable, `bit in '01'` is equivalent to `bit in ['0', '1']`: both check whether `bit` is either `'0'` or `'1'`.

`if all(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string):` is equivalent to this:

```
is_it_true = True
for bit in binary_string:
  if not (bit in '01'):
    is_it_true = False
    break

if is_it_true:
  ... # do stuff
```

See [documentation of `all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, true, but I used `not (...)` specifically to highlight how parts of the generator expression can be translated to the `for` loop approach. Thus, the `bit in '01'` part of the generator expression should be negated. Indeed, real-world code should use `not in`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down this line of code:

```
if all(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string):
```

`for bit in binary_string` : This part iterates over each character in the binary_string.

`bit in '01'`: For each character (bit), it checks if it’s either ‘0’ or ‘1’.

`all(...)`: This function checks if all the elements in the iterable (in this case, the generator expression) are True.

So, if every character in binary_string is either ‘0’ or ‘1’. If all characters satisfy this condition, the if statement evaluates to True, indicating that the input is a valid binary string.

Answer (score 0):

The `(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string)` is a generator expression which is being passed to `all`. Using a generator eliminates the need to create a temporary list holding the data, and allows early exit using the `all` function. It could be expanded to look something like this:

```py
for bit in binary_string: #iterate over a string character by character
    if bit in "01": #is the character `bit` in the string "01"? (is it a "0" or "1" char)
        continue #if the current char is "0" or "1" continue checking the rest
    else:
        return False #if not, exit early and return false
return True #if we get through the entire string and all characters are "0" or "1" return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is python generator syntax, it creates a generator which loops over each `bit` (character) in `binary_string`. These are similar to list comprehensions, so you could get a list of all the 'bits' with

```
binary_string = "0110"
[bit for bit in binary_string] == ["0", "1", "1", "0"]
```

The `bit in '01'` checks whether the `bit` is one of '0' or '1'. So if `bit = '0'` or `bit = '1'` then `bit in '01'` is True, otherwise it is  `False`.

`all` is a default function which returns `True` if all of the elements of its argument are truthy. So

```
all(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string)
```

is `True` if `bit` (character) is one of '0' or '1' for every character in `binary_string` (the input string). `if all(bit in '01' for bit in binary_string):` means the next lines of code are only executed if the string only contains '0's and '1's, in other words if it represents a valid binary number.